# How do I whitelist Truecrypt to show in the indicator area?

Tags: indicator, notification-area, truecrypt

Truecrypt installs and runs but is unable to use the Unity system tray for the program running in the background. If one exits the main program can not be restarted to unmount the encrypted volume(s). I have tried white-listing 'truecrypt' but it still does not allow the background program to appear in the system tray.

Answer (score 13):

Whitelist 'Truecrypt' instead, log out, log in again and it should show up:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Many thanks, the key step was to log out and back in again - I am using a LiveCD so used gnome-session-save --logout-dialog in a terminal

Comment: You can also press Alt+F2 and run `(unity &)`, which will restart Unity.

Comment: Where do you get that screenshot? My `gconf-editor` has not those entries.

Comment: @enzotib: the program is called `dconf-editor` and it is part of the package `dconf-tools`.

Answer (score 1):

I had a query on this issue also. This is what solved the issue for me using 11.04.

Open terminal and paste in the following:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist "['all']"
```

Then log out and back in to Ubuntu, you should see a small Truecrypt icon up by the connection/time/audio icons are in the top right corner. Use this icon to open/close the application as per normal, not the Unity interface

Answer (score 0):

open your terminal, then run:

```
gsettings get com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist
```

after add **'truecrypt'** word  (it is *case-sensitive*!) this list and set it.

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist "[<YOUR OLD LIST>, 'truecrypt']"
```

e.g.:

```
gsettings get com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist
```

['JavaEmbeddedFrame', 'Wine', 'scp-dbus-service', 'Update-notifier']

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist "['JavaEmbeddedFrame',
 'Wine', 'scp-dbus-service', 'Update-notifier', 'truecrypt']"
```