# How can I hide one wine app from the Unity panel without blacklisting all wine apps?

Tags: unity, wine

I would like a wine app to run in the background without appearing in unity's panel.

The app, by the way, is "air video server", in case that matters.

Is there any way (command line is fine) to start the application with no tray icon? 
(other than blacklisting all wine apps from the notification area , if possible)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's basically the same as [How do I whitelist Truecrypt to show in the indicator area?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35076/how-do-i-whitelist-truecrypt-to-work-under-unity) except remove Wine and don't add TrueCrypt.

Comment: I know that way, that's why i asked if there is any way other than blacklisting all wine apps. Is there any way to remove just one app?

Comment: It seems that this way is the only one right now - the only one that worked for me at least. 
Until i find a better way,this one is the "answer"

Answer (score 0):

When you invoke this particular wine application try using a differently-named symlink to wine.  This will change the name of the process in the process table.

For example, if you `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/skype /usr/local/bin/notskype` and then invoke skype with `skype` the name of the process that launches won't match the whitelist and you won't see the tray icon.  While launching with `skype` will still place the icon as before.

EDIT:  The concept works with apps like skype.  But this does **NOT** work with Wine.  I'm leaving it up for now in case someone can adapt it to wine.

Comment: seeing that the command in alacarte is "env WINEPREFIX="/home/christos/.wine" wine C:\\windows\\command\\start.exe /Unix /home/christos/.wine/dosdevices/c:/users/Public/Start\ Menu/Programs/Air\ Video\ Server/Air\ Video\ Server.lnk" i can't thing of any way to run the application without mentioning wine - and that would get it in the whitelist, wouldn't it?

Comment: No, I think it can work.  First: `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/wine /usr/local/bin/notwine`.  Then go back to alacarte and edit the launcher to: "env WINEPREFIX="/home/christos/.wine" notwine C:\\windows\\command\\start.exe /Unix /home/christos/.wine/dosdevices/c:/users/Public/Start\ Menu/Programs/Air\ Video\ Server/Air\ Video\ Server.lnk"

Comment: It wouldn't run with /usr/local/bin/notwine , so i sent it to /usr/bin/notwine. Then i run it with the command that you wrote but the icon showed up just as if I had launched it with "wine" instead of "notwine".

Comment: You're right.  There the real process turns out to be "wineserver" and I can't seem to get it to launch as anything but itself.

Comment: I guess i'll go with removing all of the wine apps from the whitelist - or just ignoring the icons that mess up the appearance of the panel.

Thanks for the help though :D