# XChat disappearing after minimize to tray

Tags: unity, 11.04, system-tray, xchat

When I click to close the XChat window, it asks whether to "Quit", "Cancel" or "Minimize to Tray". If I select "Minimize to tray" then the XChat disappears and I am not able to see the application again.

I have checked the process list and it is there in running state. Normally in earlier versions of Ubuntu it would show a XChat icon in the top panel bar.

I have not added the Xchat as sticky icon in my application panel. I hope there must be some work around or setting for it.

Answer (score 15):

I see three solutions:

1. Disable the tray icon:

   - Settings → Preferences
   - Chatting → Alerts
   - Uncheck the *Enable system tray icon* checkbox.

   Now everytime you click on 'x' window button the application will quit. If you want to minimize it, just minimize it.
2. Allow the tray icon to show. To do this, follow [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35076/how-do-i-whitelist-truecrypt-to-work-under-unity/35078#35078) and add 'Xchat' and 'xchat' to that whitelist:

   [image]

   (You need to install the package `dconf-tools` for the program `dconf-editor`.)
3. Another alternative is to integrate XChat in the messages indicator by installing the `xchat-indicator` if you are using plain XChat, or `xchat-gnome-indicator` if you are using XChat GNOME. If you close the XChat window, you'll get it back via the XChat item in the messages menu:

   [image]