# How can I re-open the TrueCrypt window after it's been closed?

Tags: unity, 11.10, unity-2d, appmenu, truecrypt

I installed TrueCrypt 7.1 Standard 64-bit on a fresh install of Ubuntu 11.10 64-bit. After  finding the application in the dash I dragged it's icon onto the Unity launcher. I then clicked that icon and TrueCrypt's main window opened. I mounted my encrypted file/volume and then closed the window to do some work. To re-open the TrueCrypt window I would normally click the small blue TrueCrypt icon that appears on the top panel. In Ubuntu 11.10 that icon is no longer there. I receive a message ("TrueCrypt is already running.") if I click on the TrueCrypt icon in the launcher.

How can I re-open the TrueCrypt window after it's been closed in Ubuntu 11.10?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I whitelist Truecrypt to work under Unity?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/35076/how-do-i-whitelist-truecrypt-to-work-under-unity)

Comment: After I got exposed to unity I realized that it is indeed a duplicate - however this question is much easier to find than the other. Someone could check if the other can be updated with some good buzzwords/searchterms before closing this one.

Answer (score 9):

For me, this didn't help. I had to also remove the Truecrypt lock file as per [these instructions](http://sebs-blog.de/truecrypt-is-already-running-what-to-do.html).

In terminal enter:

```
rm ~/.TrueCrypt-lock-USERNAME
```

Where you replace USERNAME with your username.

Answer (score 2):

On all operating systems, just starting TrueCrypt again helps. It will notice it is already running as a daemon/service in the background and reopen the window interface.

And [here's help](https://askubuntu.com/q/30742/28323) if you're hit by unity: By default Truecrypt's little notification icon is not shown in the upper right panel because unity implements a whitelist. Only applications on this whitelist may publish their icon in the upper right panel. Follow the quoted link to a question which shows how to allow all applications to publish their icon.

Comment: The first part seems not necessarily to be true. On my machine TrueCrypt reckognizes and warns me that it is already running, but does not reopen the window interface.

Answer (score 1):

A stale lockfile might cause this. I had similar issue sometimes with 11.04 the rest of the configuration was the same.

[Quote](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=9130840&postcount=1):

> If a messagebox TrueCrypt is already running appears when starting
>   TrueCrypt, check for a hidden file in the home directory of the
>   concerned user called .TrueCrypt-lock-username. Substitute username
>   with the individual username. Delete the file and start TrueCrypt
>   again.

I have found the solution here:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=9131484

Answer (score 0):

As described in the following link, you may "whitelist" truecrypt, allowing its "running" icon to be displayed with unity on the top bar.

[How do I whitelist Truecrypt to show in the indicator area?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35076/how-do-i-whitelist-truecrypt-to-work-under-unity)