# How do I whitelist only Truecrypt's notification icon?

Tags: unity, truecrypt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I whitelist Truecrypt to work under Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35076/how-do-i-whitelist-truecrypt-to-work-under-unity)

The Truecrypt icon shows when the whitelist for Unity is set as:

```
$ gsettings get com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist
['all']
```

But I do not wish to display all system tray icons. Only Truecrypt's. However setting 'Truecrypt' in whitelist does not seem to work after logging out and logging in:

```
$ gsettings get com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist
['JavaEmbeddedFrame', 'Wine', 'scp-dbus-service', 'Update-notifier', 'Truecrypt']
```

Is the name 'Truecrypt' correct?

Comment: This is an extension to the other question. The point is 'Truecrypt' (note the capitalization) as suggested there did not work.

Answer (score 1):

The right word is: `truecrypt`

(Note the capitalization)